# Two buttons side-by-side with auto fill horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-gridlayout

Here is what I'm trying to achieve: The buttons should have equals widths if the button titles are short, but the longer text should stretch the corresponding button at the expense of the other.

[image]

[image]

Here is my layout, which works used in a Fragment's or Activity's layout. But it does not correctly displayed used in a custom view of an `AlertDialog`

```xml
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="1"
    app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    app:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="Very long button title" />
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

This is the failed result, displayed in the Layout Inspector. Any ideas on how to make this layout work in this case?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here copy the layout to archive the result you want.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="large text Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```